# Why is the address of auto y = reference_to_x not the same as the address of x?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, memory-address

Suppose you have the following code:

```
long& fn2(long& another_var1, long another_var2){

    another_var1 = another_var1 + another_var2;
    another_var2 = another_var2 + another_var1;

    return another_var1;
}

int main (){
    cout << boolalpha;

    long var1 = 5;
    long var2 = 10;

    auto result = fn2(var1, var2);

    cout << &result << endl;
    cout << &var1 << endl;
    cout << result << endl; //Line 1
    cout << (&result == &var1) << endl; //Line 2 
}
```

Everything works as expected until you reach `Line 2`, where `false` is returned. When you `auto` `result`, it is supposed to be a reference variable to `another_var1`, which is a reference to `var1`, i.e. they should all have the same address - they are just name aliases for the same memory. Looking at `Line 1`, 15 is returned, giving the illusion that they are all the same. Then, `Line 2` disproves that.

I think, however, this may be an issue with `auto`. If you delete `auto` and replace it with its true return type `long&`, you get the expected results.

Can anyone explain what is really happening?

Comment: `auto` defaults to non-reference if I remember correctly.

Comment: `auto result` is a value, `auto& result` might do the trick.

Comment: @user4581301 indeed that is why. That is so dumb.

Comment: @user4581301 The opposite would be unexpected and dangerous.

Comment: I won't go as far as dumb, just as far as counter intuitive. It's hard to remove the reference if you don't want it, and easy to add it if you do.

Comment: True, true. For some reason, that didn't even occur to me to think of adding the `&`. It's just frustrating.

Comment: @user4581301 if you find this unintuitive then I'd suggest updating your intuition about references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When you `auto result`, it is supposed to be a reference variable to `another_var1`

Here's your bug. If `result` is supposed to be a reference, then you must declare a reference. Like this:

```
auto& result = fn2(var1, var2);
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to declare a reference explicitly -- `decltype(auto)` behaves more like the way the OP was expecting `auto` to behave and would also result in a reference here.

Comment: @hvd Please edit this or make a new answer to show that magic.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I think it would be better as an edit to this answer, but I also think it would be rude for me to edit it in myself. Let's wait to see what user2079303 thinks of it first.

Answer (score 1):

## What is really happening

`auto` deduces the type of the variable from the type of the variable used to initialize it<sup>1</sup>. I can't find anyone actually comes out and says it<sup>2</sup>, but I suspect the reference is not deduced because there is no such thing as a reference variable. References don't exist as independent entities. They are just a handy-dandy new name, [an alias](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs), for an existing variable. Once all of the referencing is resolved

```
auto result = fn2(var1, var2);
```

might as well be

```
fn2(var1, var2);
auto result = var1;
```

## How do I get what I expected?

Declare the new variable as a reference with

```
auto & result = fn2(var1, var2);
```

If you are building for C++14 or a more recent standard, [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) can be used to track the returned type's value category, an [lvalue reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), to retain the reference.

```
decltype(auto) result = fn2(var1, var2);
```

<sup>1</sup> [Gory details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). Note how it uses the same deduction rules as templates. Why repeat yourself?

<sup>2</sup> [No longer true](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/). I should know better than to neglect checking with Herb Sutter or Scott Meyers first.